# Don't escape a backslash with regex in ngTagsInput

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-tags-input

I'm using ngTagsInput in my Angular app and I want only specific tags to be allowed. - to achieve this am using:

```
allowedTagsPattern: '(?!story|pick\b)\b\w+'
```

(this `allowedTagsPattern` accepts a regex).

The issue I am facing is those backslashes are not being processed as I want, I've tried to escape them using:

```
allowedTagsPattern: '(?!story|pick\\b)\\b\\w+'
```

But that doesn't work.

Also to note, I know the regex works as I can apply it to the `tags-input` on the HTML side as `allowed-tags-pattern="(?!story|pick\\b)\\b\\w+"` and its find

Any ideas on what I need to do?

**UPDATE**

I think its something todo with ngTagsInput - I tried a really basic regex, literally: `allowedTagsPattern: 'a'` and that also failed to working - giving the error `angular.js:13550 TypeError: a.allowedTagsPattern.test is not a function`

Comment: Perhaps, a regex object inside a string? `'/\b(?!(?:story|pick)\b)\w+/'`? Could you show a fiddle?

Comment: That doesnt seem to work

Comment: try this: allowed-tags-pattern="(?!story|pick\\\b)\\\b\\\w+"

Comment: Well, `allowedTagPattern` should be a string acc. to http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/documentation/api, and `"\\b(?!(?:story|pick)\\b)\\w+"` should work. Strange. Try `allowed-tags-pattern="\\b(?!(?:story|pick)\\b)\\w+"`

Comment: Nope - 3 blackslashes dont seem to do it. As per my update above I think its an issue with ngTags

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks howeverr no luck with taht either - i did a typeOf check just to ensure nothing odd, and its def. a string